# how to keep only lines with specific word

Tags: filter

I have a huge text with multiple columns and rows and I want to keep the lines that consist one specific word (no matter in which column)...

(if possible I also like to have two  separate specific words ( I can do this after making the first one if it is difficult))

Answer (score 4):

Read `man grep`.

Do something like:

```
grep -w 'word' the_file
grep -E -w 'word1|word2' the_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Below command you can use Tested and worked fine

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (($i == "word1") || ($i == "word2")) {print $0}}}'  filename
```

Comment: What's `NF`? How to determine it (automatically)? Btw: This doesn't work for me (with white spaces as words), even with a specified number.